# OpenLayers.Format.GML parser problem?

Tags: wfs, openlayers-2, gml

I'm trying to parse WFS reponse using `OpenLayers.Format.GML` parser. However, an exception thrown in my try-catch block is `TypeError: a is undefined`.

```
protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    version: "1.1.0",
    url: WFS_HOST,
    featureType: "pl",
    featureNS: "ws",
    srsName: "EPSG:900913"
});

wfsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("PE Vector", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    protocol: protocol
});

var _Callback = function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    console.log(resp.error);

    try {
        var gmlParser = new OpenLayers.Format.GML();
        gmlParser.extractAttributes = true;
        var features = gmlParser.read(resp.responseText);

        if(features){
            for(var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                var feature = features[i];
                                    // More operations
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {
        alert("Error: " + e);
    }
};

response = protocol.read({
    maxFeatures: 100,
    callback: _Callback
});
```

My environment: GeoServer 2.1.3, OpenLayers 2.11, PostGIS 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by updating the `_Callback` variable to:

```
var _Callback = function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    console.log(resp.error);

    try {
        var gmlParser = new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v3();
        gmlParser.extractAttributes = true;
        var features = gmlParser.read(resp.priv.responseXML);

        if(features){
            for(var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                var feature = features[i];
                // TODO: More operations
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {
        alert("Error: " + e);
    }
};
```